# At least one role must be specified

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identity in my asp.net MVC  core  application , I'm getting this error when i run the application(ctrl +F5).

> InvalidOperationException: At least one role must be specified.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.RolesAuthorizationRequirement..ctor(IEnumerable allowedRoles)

my  dbContext class `appdbcontextClass` and extended class

```
public class ApppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApppDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            //options.
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(
                new Employee
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Mark",
                    Department = Department.IT,
                    Email = "abc@gmail.com"
                }
                );
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    }
```

extended class

```
  public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: From the error , it  means that no roles are provided when using RolesAuthorization. If you use the operations like `[Authorize(Roles="")]` somewhere , the error will occur when Roles is an empty string. The existing code is helpless to reproduce the issue , could you share more details?

Comment: yes , thanks i got it